# Conflit between AVAudioRecorder and AVAudioPlayer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, avaudioplayer, avaudiorecorder

here is my problem :

The code (FooController) :

```
   NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mySound" ofType:@"m4v"]; 
    soundEffect = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]  error:NULL];
[soundEffect play];
    // MicBlow
    micBlow = [[MicBlowController alloc]init];
```

And MicBlowController contains :

```
        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/dev/null"];
    NSDictionary *settings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 44100.0],                 AVSampleRateKey,
                              [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatAppleLossless], AVFormatIDKey,
                              [NSNumber numberWithInt: 1],                         AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                              [NSNumber numberWithInt: AVAudioQualityMax],         AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,
                              nil];
```

and

```
[recorder updateMeters];
const double ALPHA = 0.05;
double peakPowerForChannel = pow(10,(0.05*[recorder peakPowerForChannel:0]));
lowPassResults = ALPHA * peakPowerForChannel + (1.0 - ALPHA) * lowPassResults;

NSLog(@"Average input: %f Peak input %f Low pass results: %f",[recorder averagePowerForChannel:0],[recorder peakPowerForChannel:0],lowPassResults);
```

If I play the background sound and try to get the peak from the mic I get this log :
Average input: 0.000000 Peak input -120.000000 Low pass results: 0.000001

But if I comment all parts about AVAudioPlayer it works. I think there is a problem of channel.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, I've found the solution and it is AVAudioSession !

By using the method setCategory (with AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord as argument) I can play sounds and record sounds from the mic.

```
audioSession = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] retain];
[audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error: nil];
[audioSession setActive:YES error: nil];
```

Comment: Don't suppress error returns. Any method that has one can fail in some way; when that happens, you will want to know how it failed, so that you can prevent it from failing or recover from the failure gracefully.

Comment: Great work! This solution worked for me too. But as Peter said, if you're having problems, don't suppress the errors.

Comment: Why are you retaining a singleton?